# Service is stuck when using @CacheResult

Tags: java, caching, quarkus

I'm trying to cache some expensive db operations in my quarkus project.
But when I'm adding a `@CacheResult` annotation, the program is getting stuck before the method execution.

Class is annotated as `@ApplicationScoped`.
There's also `@Transactional` annotation.

Method looks like:

```
    @Override
    @CacheResult(cacheName = "some-chain")
    public List<UUID> getChain(@CacheKey UUID someId){
        // Call to the Spring Data repository and some additional logic
    }
```

Thread dump shows that everything is in `Waiting` or `Runnable` state.

It looks like a deadlock. Dear community, please help me to solve it )

PS. When I remove request to DB from this method, everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you post the thread dump? Thanks!

Comment: Dump: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uoLv6ko_UUVNX6mihpS532_xC9S0mddrKnw6s2jW0-U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet added in comment

Comment: Could you create an issue on our GitHub? I'll ping Gwenneg and Ben Mannes there. If you can come up with a small reproducer, that would be even better.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7548